# Как рассчитать CRC16 Modbus RTU C#

Tags: c#, .net, modbus, crc

Столкнулся с проблемой, взял пример для расчета CRC16 Modbus на C# [отсюда](http://comfiletech.com/blog/modbus-crc-algorithm-for-net/) 
Код скомпилировал, создал юнит-тест:

```
    [Test]
    public void Crc16AnciCalculateTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new byte[] { 0x37, 0x4B }, Crc16AnciUtility.ComputeChecksumBytes(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }));
    }
```

И он не проходит. Сверял с несколькими онлайн калькуляторами, например вот [такой](https://crccalc.com/)

Ввожу в калькуляторе 123456789 и выбираю input ASCI: результат для Modbus - 0x4B37. В моем случае:

```
byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

возвращает - B20E

Я подумал, что неверный пример. Взял нугет Tako.CRC, набросал консольное приложение:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        CRCManager crcManager = new CRCManager() {DataFormat = EnumOriginalDataFormat.HEX};
        var provider = crcManager.CreateCRCProvider(EnumCRCProvider.CRC16Modbus);

        var status = provider.GetCRC(bytes);
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        foreach (var b in bytes)
        {
            Console.Write(b + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Output: {status.CrcHexadecimal}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

В результате получил такое же значение...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму, почему с онлайн калькуляторами значение не совпадает? Может я не правильно ввожу данные? Но я пробовал даже по одному числу или строку вводить, все равно не сходятся результаты. Кому верить? Буду рад за разъяснения и помощь, заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ой ой ой, решил проблему, все сходится. Не верно делал ввод данных. Метод принимает массив байт, я в него передавал целые числа. Если передавать Hex, то все совпадает.

```
byte[] bytes = {0x23, 0x25};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]